# What does $a^b$ mean in the definition of a cartesian closed category?

Tags: category-theory, definition

From Mac Lane's Category Theory:

What does the symbol $c^b$ mean in the red circle in the picture below?

I see that for $\langle F, G, \phi \rangle: C \rightarrow C$ to be an adjoint it must be the case that $\phi_{x,a}=C(x \times b, a) \cong C(x, a^b)$

but if $b$ and $a$ are objects, what is meant by an object $a^b$?

---

[image]

Comment: It's just the notation used for the adjoint.

Comment: What do you mean?  Are you saying the object $c^b$ is an adjoint?

Comment: Yes. $c^b$ is defined as the image at $c$ of the adjoint of the functor $a\mapsto a\times b$.

Comment: Incidentally, the reason it's called that is that $\text{Hom}(1, c^b) \cong \text{Hom}(b, c)$ by adjunction. In particular, if $c$ and $b$ are finite sets, $|c^b| = |c|^{|b|}$. For more information see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponential+object.

Answer (score 1):

To spell out Arnaud D.'s comment...

It's just a name. The exact same thing is happening with $a\times b$ and with $t$.

As Arnaud D. states, we are assuming the existence of a right adjoint to (among other things) $-\times b$. That is, we're assuming that for each $b$ there is a functor $F_b$ such that $-\times b \dashv F_b$. We simply choose to write $F_b(a)$ as $a^b$ as that's more evocative.